# Obtener valores dentro de un Objeto que sus claves vienen del endpoint de forma dinamica - TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Estoy trabajando sobre un objeto en JavaScript que puede venir con claves dinámicas desde mi endpoint, cada clave devuelve un arreglo. Estoy intentando encontrar de forma dinámica si una clave existe para obtener los valores que esta tiene pero solo he podido saber que existe pero no puedo acceder a la informacion que contiene esa clave. Esta es la estructura del objeto que recibo del endpoint:

```
"todosModelos": {
    "dimension": [
        "23"
    ],
    "color": [
        "Verde",
        "Negro"
    ]
},
```

Y las posibles claves estan en un arreglo de objetos que es el siguiente:

```
const todosTiposClaves = [{
    name: 'Color',
    code: 'color'
  },
  {
    name: 'Dimesión',
    code: 'dimension'
  },
  {
    name: 'Calidad',
    code: 'calidad'
  },
  {
    name: 'Durabilidad',
    code: 'durabilidad'
  }];
```

Y todosModelos tiene el siguiente tipado:

```
    export interface TodosTiposClavesInterfaces {
  color?: string[];
  dimension?: string[];
  calidad?: string[];
  durabilidad?: string[];
}
```

Este es el metodo que estoy intentando usar pero me quedo hasta el punto que solo detecto que la calve existe:

```
export const makeArrayDataRadioNewVariations = (todosTiposClaves, todosModelos) => {
        
        let array:RadioOptions[] = [];
    
        todosTiposClaves.map((item, idx) => {
    
          const hasKey = Object.values(todosModelos).some(x => x == item.code);
    
          if(hasKey){
    
            console.log('devolver el arreglo segun la clave encontrada') 
          }
        });
    
        return console.log(array);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Alguna idea de como obtener los valores de las claves de forma dinámica? Necesito una vez que alguna clave sea encontrada obtener un array de objetos de la siguiente forma:

```
array.push({
        label: (nombre de la clave), 
        name: (nombre de la clave),
        values: (array que contenia esa clave en el array anterior) 
      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes utilizar al método [**`hasOwnProperty()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty), ya que se encarga de devolver un valor booleano si el objeto `todosModelos` tiene una propiedad que sea igual al valor de su parámetro, que en este caso sería `item`, y `item` sería cada elemento de tu array `todosTiposClaves`.

---

#### Pasos:

1. Primero necesitamos recorrer tu array, podemos hacerlo con `forEach`:

   ```js
   todosTiposClaves.forEach((item) => {
     // ...
   }
   ```
2. Ahora validamos si el elemento del array se encuentra en una de las propiedades del objeto `todosModelos`:

   ```js
   todosTiposClaves.forEach((item) => {
     if (todosModelos.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
       //...
     }
   });
   ```
3. Si esto cumple, asignamos a una variable (llamado `values`) el valor de ese `item` encontrado, y luego pusheamos a un array esa variable.

   ```js
   todosTiposClaves.forEach((item) => {
     if (todosModelos.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
       const values = todosModelos[item];
       array.push(...values);
     }
   });
   ```
4. Para obtener el formato deseado, podemos pushear al array de la siguiente forma:

   ```js
   todosTiposClaves.forEach((item) => {
     if (todosModelos.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
       const values = todosModelos[item];
       array.push({ label: item, name: item, values: [...values] });
     }
   });
   ```

---

#### Código:

```js
const makeArrayDataRadioNewVariations = (todosTiposClaves, todosModelos) => {
  let array = [];

  todosTiposClaves.forEach((item) => {
    if (todosModelos.hasOwnProperty(item)) {
      const values = todosModelos[item];
      array.push({ label: item, name: item, values: [...values] });
    }
  });

  return array;
};

const todosModelos = {
  "dimension": ["23"],
  "color": ["Verde", "Negro"]
};

const todosTiposClaves1 = ['color', 'dimension', 'calidad', 'durabilidad'];
const todosTiposClaves2 = ['color', 'calidad', 'durabilidad']; // Omitimos a la clave "dimension".

console.log(makeArrayDataRadioNewVariations(todosTiposClaves1, todosModelos));
console.log(makeArrayDataRadioNewVariations(todosTiposClaves2, todosModelos));
```

Comment: Gracias por su pronta respuesta, pero edite la pregunta para que la salida de la funcion sea en una forma en especifico

Comment: Ok estimado, no problem

Comment: @albertolg89 modifiqué mi respuesta, me avisa si esto es lo que necesita.

Comment: estoy teniendo este problema. Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'AttributesOfNewVariations'.
  No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'AttributesOfNewVariations'

Comment: voy a poner algunas ediciones a la pregunta. para que puedas ver con mas claridad por el dichoso typeScript

Comment: Debiste especificar en la **etiqueta y título** que estás usando TypeScript y no JavaScript, mi código es completamente JavaScript y es común que tengas esos errores de tipados (ya que JS nunca se queja por sus tipos, **pero TS sí**). En este caso podrías cambiar el tipo de dato de `AttributesOfNewVariations` agregando esta línea de código al inicio: `type AttributesOfNewVariations = { [key: string]: string[]; };` y luego tu objeto `todosModelos` podría quedar algo como esto: `const todosModelos: AttributesOfNewVariations = { ... }`, prueba y me avisas.

Comment: Ya lo adicione al typeScript y me funciona perfecto

Comment: Me alegro que te haya funcionado, saludos.